# Right Adjoint of Hom Functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I was looking at a list of examples of adjunctions, and came across the following example:

$$- \times B: \operatorname{Set} \rightarrow \operatorname{Set}$$ has a right adjoint $$ \operatorname{Hom}(B, -). $$

I'm new to category theory, and I'm having trouble seeing why this is. I know that to prove this I need to show that $$\operatorname{Set}(A \times B, C) \cong \operatorname{Set}(A, \operatorname{Hom}(B,C)) $$

but how do I go about this?

**Edit:** Thanks to the comment by @Mark, I understand how to construct the bijection. But how do I show that it is natural? Am I missing something simple?

Comment: This may be easier if you note that $A\times B$ is a categorical product in the category of Sets.

Comment: I know that, but how does it help?

Comment: What's the universal property of the product?

Comment: I'm not sure what this universal property is. I came up with this idea: is the bijection between functions from $A$ to $C$, where I fix the element of $B$ that is in the function?

Comment: The naturality requirement is that this isomorphism should be natural in $A$ and $C$ (contravariantly in $A$ and covariantly in $C$)

Comment: You fix the element of $A$.  Essentially, $f:A\times B\to C$ is a function like $f(a,b) = c$.  Then, define the function $g:A\to (B\to C)$ by $g(a) = f(a,\cdot)$.  This $g(a):B\to C$ is in the desired Hom-set.

Comment: I see! How do I show that this is natural, though? Do I need to find a natural transformation?

Comment: You don't need to look very far to find a natural transformation; it's in the comment by @Mark .  The natural transformation you want sends any $f\in\text{Set}(A\times B,C)$ to the $g$ defined in that comment.